# makefile fails when deleting a file

Tags: shell, make

I am trying to write makefile and check - if a folder exist - delete it :

```
BINUTILS_TAR_GZ := binutils-2.25.tar.gz
BINUTILS_ORIG := binutils-2.25
BINUTILS_CHANGES := binutils_changes
.
.
.
clean:
    @echo "checking $(BINUTILS_ORIG)"
    @if [ -e ./$(BINUTILS_ORIG) ]; then \
        rm -rf ./$(BINUTILS_ORIG)
    fi
    @echo "done"
```

but I am getting "/bin/sh: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file" all the time. What am I doing wrong ? running centos 6

Comment: You forgot to add a `\ ` at the end of the `rm` line.

Comment: yes and the ; as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
clean:
    @echo "checking $(BINUTILS_ORIG)"
    @if [ -e ./$(BINUTILS_ORIG) ]; then \
        rm -rf ./$(BINUTILS_ORIG) ;\
    fi
```

a `;\` was missing.

Comment: Explanation: make runs each line in a separate sub-shell, unless you force it otherwise e.g. by putting everything on one line or escaping line endings.